# Mysql and php to display following data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help, I have MySQL table data and it contains the following columns:

```
username
userid
birthstate
```

My goal is to display the total number of users that have a specific birth state.  I cannot manually write a query. Can I sort the data in another way?

The output I need is stated below, suppose abc, def, and ghi are birthStates.

1. abc = total no of user of birth_state abc
2. def = total no of user of birth_state def
3. ghi = total no of user of birth_state ghi

State name and count of all the available birthstate in the table.

Comment: If you are not writing the query then how do you get the data from the MySQL database?

Comment: I think he meant he doesn't want to write `select from where state = california; select from where state = oregon; etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following query to achieve this

```
Select birth_state, count(*) as total_count from user_data group by birth_state;

Output:

birth_state | total_count

xyz         | 2
ABC         | 3
```

Where user_data is the table name and birth_state is column name in which birth state is stored.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the total numbers of Users in each state which I *think* is what you're looking for you could use a group by...

```
Select birthstate, Count(*)
From tablename
Group By birthstate
```

Comment: how to display that data in page using php.

Comment: Follow the W3 tutorial on php and mysql, but basically open connection, perform query, echo results.  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

u want to display total number of users in each state.

```
Select *, Count(*) as total From tablename Group By birthstate
```